# How to add 301 redirects to only all 404 error pages of domain.com (say domain.com/aaa) to exact newdomain.com/aaa page with htaccess redirect rule?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a website named `example.com`. I have moved it to `old.example.com`. Now `example.com/aaa` page is showing a 404 error. But `old.example.com/aaa` is available. Like this, there are thousands of broken links on `example.com`. I want to redirect `example.com/aaa` to the exact URL on `old.example.com`, which is `old.example.com/aaa`. Is this possible with the `.htaccess`?

Comment: Is that http status 404 raised by some application logic or is it the http server itself not being able to map the requests to existing files or directories in the file system?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand this. But the pages are not available as I have moved the website from domain.com to old.domain.com. So now pages like domain.com/aaa.htm are showing 404 errors. I want to write something so that all redirects happen itself like this. If a 404 error hits on domain.com/aaa.htm, I want to redirect it automatically to old.domain.com/aaa.htm. Is that possible please with htaccess?

Comment: I will try to phrase it differently... What does "pages are not available" actually mean? What are "pages" for you? A http server typically delivery either objects in the file system (documents, images) or it delegates processing by means of request rewriting to some application logic, a script, maybe a website framework. An http status 404 will typically get raised wither if the documents or images do not exist on the file system or if the application logic the request is processed by _decides_ to return a 404, since the request targets a resource the logic cannot or does not want to deliver.

Comment: I would suggesting asking this question on [webmasters.se].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a webmastering question.